# Detecting non-alpha pixels for plotting 2D terrain

Tags: java, graphics, jframe, jcomponent

Looking for possibly a quick solution to aid in optimizing my workflow. I built a Java based level editor for a mobile game and have a process that takes quite a while: Plotting the terrain for interpretation by the physics engine. I have to turn my mouse sensitivity way down to increase accuracy, and it drives me nuts to click that much. Plus, programmers are natively lazy :-D

If this system worked the way I wanted, it would start at the top of the graphics layer (0, 0) run down the layer until it bumped a non-alpha pixel, move over five or so pixels and repeat until the general terrain is plotted.

[image]

I have the plotting/editing system setup on a scroll wheel so I can move to individual points and insert more points and delete to take care of terrain elements that were not captured.

This question may require more information at this point of which I am willing to provide. I just don't know what's possible at this point so please be patient.

Comment: Are you plotting the little red dots in the image above, or the numbers on the terrain?

Comment: Red dots, the very edge of the terrain.

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution to this?